# Trying to divide a number by another number in GCC (Intel X86-64)

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64

In my .data section, I have a number N declared as .quad 0xE4

in Main, I use the instruction mov $N, %rdx
Next, I want to divide the value of N by 10.

I've tried mov $10, %rax
and then div %rax

but it's not working.

I am very new to assembler and would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Division assumes the numerator is combined RDX:RAX and is divided by the register or by a 64 bit value at a particular memory location. You probably want to zero out _RDX_ put `$N` in _RAX_ and then do the division by 10 using some other register. How about `XOR %RDX, %RDX` (same as RDX=0) followed by `MOV N, %RAX` and then `MOV $10, %RCX` `DIV %RCX`

Comment: It's the same problem every time. If only people just searched..